# How to make position of div change when accessing the website over the phone

Tags: html, css

So, I have two divs one is one the left side and contains vertical menu, and the other is on the right. Does anyone know how can I put that left one on the top and make it a horizontal menu, when someone is accessing the website using the phone?
Here is my css for those two divs, levi is left one and desni is the right one. Thanks!

```
    #levi{
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f4654e;
    position:fixed;
    max-width:90%;
    }

    #desni{
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    overflow: auto;
    width:75%;
    left:value;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Use CSS media queries - @media all and (max-width:760px) { ... your css for smaller screens ... }

Comment: You're welcome, btw where are you from, I see that you're using `levi`, `desni` ;)

Comment: Me too, if you need any additional help go to my profile and contact me through Skype or other ways I provided there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like mdesdev commented above, what you're looking for is "Media Queries"

```
@media (max-width:768px) { 
    Mobile specific CSS goes here... 
}
```

Or, if you have a separate stylesheet for your mobile specific CSS, then you can link to it like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 768px)" href="mobile_specific.css" />
```

See this link for more information on how to use them:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

And this link for more info on specific screen widths (a little dated, but still useful):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @mdesdev Thanks! Credit to you though for being the first to mention it!

Comment: I just land on the question first and comment, you provide a nice answer, keep it that way and you gonna have a nice rep here ;)